# Anime movie with mind control headsets

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I'm almost 100% positive it aired on Toonami in the 2000s, somewhere between 2001 and 2011. The movie's antagonist used headsets on people to basically control them (I think). I vividly remember a scene where one of the characters heart was beating very fast and then it just bursted, and that was a result of the mind control headset thing. There was a scene towards the end of the movie where one of the main characters saved their friend from the headset and heart thingy and when they removed the headset (or helmet) he had a small hole in his forehead (I think). These are really all the details I remember.

I've done a lot of searching but cannot seem to find it anywhere, please help.

Comment: Could you please tell us the genre, for example, is this a mecha anime like Gundam? Was it set in Japan?

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the blue: [Grey: Digital Target](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/69,grey-digital-target/screenshots)

> Grey is a laconic trooper in a rough, futuristic military system which rewards success in battle with high pay and promotions, but only three precent of troopers live long enough for the final goal - citizenship, and the chance for a life above the misery of most of the populace. Grey has managed to keep coming back alive, even earning the nickname Grey Death, but is the society he’s fought for worth it

Luckily for you there aren't that many anime movies dubbed into English that released before 2012, so you could just take a look at [all of them](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/index?char=all&type=1&synchro=en&from_date=1970-01-01&to_date=2012-01-01&to_episode=1&sort=date&order=asc&view=4&title=en,fr,de,it,es&titlex=1,2).

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: @Valorum it's the only one where characters wear something on their head that I could find.

Comment: The film is available on youtube. Perhaps you could point at some relevant scenes?

Comment: @Valorum The one where they wear something on their head, which is most of the time. It's illegally on YouTube, so I removed the link and put one up for a database that provides some pictures instead.

Comment: @Valorum No, that's not how copyright works. You are thinking about trademarks. Copyright is a state granted monopoly that you cannot lose by inaction.

Comment: @Valorum By the absence of a valid copyright notice. Most likely the international publisher no longer even owns the right to distribute this movie, since these kind of deals are limited to a few years. (Which is also why when re-releasing old anime they sometimes get new dubs, like in the case of Evangelion. The rights to the anime return to the Japanese, but the rights to the dub remain with the English distributor, who might have gone under already.) So unless the original distributor of the dub still has a deal with the Japanese it is impossible to make the old dub legally available.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything in your answer that constitutes evidence that this is the right film, other than that people wear headbands

Comment: @Valorum I never claimed I had any evidence. It's a shot in the blue. A shot in the dark. A random shot. A crapshoot. Etc.